# How to retrieve values from junction table as a String?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in MYSQL, VideoCategory is the junction table between Video and category

```
Video
Category
VideoCategory
```

it means: each video can bleong to many categories (VideoCategory) table.

My goal is to retrieve a "SMART" way of these values: it means: 
Video, Comma Delimied String of Categories

ex:

```
"video1", "1, 2, 3"
"video2", "1, 4"
"video"3", ""
```

(video 3 has no categories assigned)

Any idea on how to do that without using mysql loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and a couple of `join`s should do the trick:

```
SELECT video.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(category.name ORDER BY category.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM   video v
JOIN   videocategory vc ON v.id = videocategory.video_id
JOIN   category c ON videocategory.category_id = c.id
```